# PHP - Poll posting arrays in database

Tags: php, html

I'm making a school poll and I've found one that suited my needs as a newbie [here](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-design-and-create-a-php-powered-poll/). However I'm having a problem with it posting arrays when I tried changing the option from radio to checkbox. Here's the code:

```html
<?php require_once('Connections/conn_vote.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO poll (id, question) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Poll'], "text"));
        
  mysql_select_db($database_conn_vote, $conn_vote);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $conn_vote) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "pollsgt.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

$colname_rs_vote = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['recordID'])) {
  $colname_rs_vote = $_GET['recordID'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_conn_vote, $conn_vote);
$query_rs_vote = sprintf("SELECT * FROM poll WHERE id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_vote, "int"));
$rs_vote = mysql_query($query_rs_vote, $conn_vote) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_vote = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_vote);
$totalRows_rs_vote = mysql_num_rows($rs_vote);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>2017 CES Elections</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<fieldset>
 <legend>Select at most two from the following candidates.</legend>
 
 <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" id="form1" name="form1" method="POST">
 <div id="subscriber_1" class="subscriber">
  <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Poll[]" value="bm1" id="Poll_0" />
      <img src="images/bm1.jpg" align="center">
  Candidate 1 <i>(SMM)</i>
  </label>
     <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Poll[]" value="bm2" id="Poll_1" />
  <img src="images/bm2.jpg" align="center">
       Candidate 2 <i>(SMAM)</i>
     </label>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Poll[]" value="bm3" id="Poll_2" />
  <img src="images/bm3.jpg" align="center">
       Candidate 3 <i>(SMAM)</i>
     </label>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Poll[]" value="bm4" id="Poll_3" />
  <img src="images/bm4.jpg" align="center">
       Candidate 4 <i>(SMM)</i>
  </label>
 </div>
    <center>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Next" /></input>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="form1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" /> 
 </center>
 </form>
</fieldset>
<script>
$('.subscriber :checkbox').change(function () {
    var $cs=$(this).closest('.subscriber').find(':checkbox:checked');
    if ($cs.length > 2) {
        this.checked=false;
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($rs_vote);
?>
```

However when I run the code the database picks up an array and not an individual vote.

[image: IMAGE HERE]

How do I make it post separate values that are not arrays? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The variable `$_POST['Poll']` is probably an array, please try to use `var_dump` on it to see its content during debugging.

Comment: You should have seen a PHP notice about an "array to string conversion" while running this code. If you didn't you're developing without errors showing, which is really bad practice. You should set `display_errors=On` in your php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string interpretation of `$_POST['Poll']` to be stored in the database change your code for $insertSQL with this:

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO poll (id, question) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString(implode(",", $_POST['Poll']), "text"));
```

Comment: Is there a way for the two values to have a different ID in the database? For now I can see that when I select the first two candidates, there is only one 'id' in the database and the 'question' has the values "bm1,bm2". My results.php cannot interpret that.